# Is there any way to export the renderscript to *.jar without manual copying the *.bc?

Tags: java, eclipse, renderscript

I implement a function using renderscript and I would like to export it as a part of my library. I try to export it on Eclipse, but it needs the id of *.bc which is generated in R.java. Then I copy the *.bc to the target resource folder and it works. Is there any way to export the renderscript to *.jar without manual copying the *.bc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse build rules should take care of embedding the .bc file in your resources already. Perhaps you mean something different by "export", but you can only use the RS bitcode and kernels that you write using our Java or NDK RenderScript APIs. The function wouldn't be available to link against traditional JNI code or anything like that.